# Is there a way to get Nginx proxy_cache expiration time?

Tags: nginx

This is my nginx proxy_cache config:

```
proxy_cache cache_one;
location ~ \.(jpg|png|gif) {
    proxy_cache_valid 1d;
}
```

It's worked but I never know the images expiration time in any way

I wanna add a header for expiration time like this:

```
location ~ \.(jpg|png|gif) {
    proxy_cache_valid 1d;
    add_header expires $proxy_cache_expires;
}
```

Is this possible? how can I get `$proxy_cache_expires` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All available nginx variable from HTTP Proxy Module was listed [in this page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#variables) and all nginx variable was listed [in this page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html). Currently, nginx only expose several variables: `$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for`, `$proxy_host` and `$proxy_port`.

Of course you can achieve it by writing LUA/perl script to inspect the cache file. To give you an idea, here the [bash script](https://github.com/perusio/nginx-cache-inspector) from [António P. P. Almeida a.k.a perusio](https://github.com/perusio) that can be used to inspect nginx proxy properties, such as expiration time.